# Add value to every "other" field ((i+j)%2==0) of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an `m`-by-`n` numpy array, and I'd like to add 1.0 to all entries `[i, j]` when `(i + j) % 2 == 0`, i.e., "to every other square".

I could of course simply iterate over the fields

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(5, 4)

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
            a[i, j] += 1.0
```

but needless to say this is really slow.

Any idea of how to improve on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily do the operation in two steps, like

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((5, 14))

# Even rows, odd columns
a[::2, 1::2] += 1
# Odd rows, even columns
a[1::2, ::2] += 1

print a
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
a[(np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None] + np.arange(a.shape[1]))%2==0] += 1
```

**Explanation :** We basically create two arrays that are equivalent of the `i-th` and `j-th` iterators. Let's call them `I` and `J`.

```
I = np.arange(a.shape[0])
J = np.arange(a.shape[1])
```

Now, to perform an operation between all possible `i` and `j`, we create extend `I` to `2D` by *pushing* its elements into the first axis and thus creating singleton dimension along its second axis.

Figuratively, the effect of  broadcasting could be put like this :

```
    I[:,None] : M , 1
            J : 1 , N
I[:,None] + J : M,  N
```

Thus, the final setting would be -

```
a[(I[:,None] + J)%2==0] += 1
```

To put it other way with the intention to avoid comparing with `0` and directly use `mod-2` which would be essentially `0` or `1` -

```
a += (np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]-1 + np.arange(a.shape[1]))%2
```

---

One can also use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to process odd and then even rows for setting, like so -

```
a[np.ix_(np.arange(0,a.shape[0],2),np.arange(0,a.shape[1],2))] += 1
a[np.ix_(np.arange(1,a.shape[0],2),np.arange(1,a.shape[1],2))] += 1
```

Comment: could please add some explanation? Would surely help newbies to understand it in a better way.

Comment: I think the `np.xi_` solution should get more emphasis; it's about twice as fast.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Well the broadcasting strike me first, so that came up at the top :)

Answer (score 1):

One can build a mask for "every other" element, and apply the addition on the mask.

```
# Create mask
m00 = np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype=bool)
m00[0::2] = True
m01 = np.zeros(a.shape[1], dtype=bool)
m01[0::2] = True
m0 = np.logical_and.outer(m00, m01)

m10 = np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype=bool)
m10[1::2] = True
m11 = np.zeros(a.shape[1], dtype=bool)
m11[1::2] = True
m1 = np.logical_and.outer(m10, m11)

m = np.logical_or(m0, m1)
a[m] += 1
```