# Use numpy to create matrix based on conditional indices of an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I would like to create an `n by m` matrix based on elements of an `n + m` length array.

Here a simple double for loop suffices, but I wish for an expedient solution. The matrix will be relatively small.

```
n = 4
m = 6
s = n + m

array = np.arange(s)  # note: arange is only for example. real array varies.
matrix = np.zeros((n,m))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range (m):
        matrix[i,j] = array[i+j]
```

I have found that a comprehension is faster than the double for loops

```
matrix3 = [[array[i+j] for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
```

Is there a faster way?

An additional bonus would be to incorporate the modulo operator. I only actually need the indices where `i+j % 2 == 0`. In the double for loop the modulo method seems a little bit faster, but this may not be convenient or expedient for generating this matrix via numpy.

It is fine to not do this, since matrix multiplcation will occur after and the necessary elements will be multiplied by zero anyways. My mentioning the modulo is only in the off-case that this leads to a faster solution.

for this MWE

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range (m):
        if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
            matrix[i,j] = array[i+j]
```

### note:

I ask for a numpy solution under the assumption numpy will be fastest, but any pure python (including numpy/scipy) solution is fine so long as it is faster than pure python double for loops

### motivation:

I am trying to remove all dependencies on arrays from a double for loop so that I can use broadcasting rather than a double for loop. This is the last array left

Comment: `arr[:, None]+ arr`

Comment: this does not seem to work. I don't see how it would know what shape to make it? the end result wouldn't be an n by m matrix would it? wouldn't this make an (n+m) by (n+m) matrix?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [hankel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html) matrix:

```
>>> from scipy.linalg import hankel
>>> matrix = hankel(array[0:n], array[n:s])
>>> matrix
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7],
       [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

If you absolutely want to set elements where `(i+j)%2==1` to zero you can do ([original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204283/add-value-to-every-other-field-ij2-0-of-numpy-array)):

```
>>> matrix[::2, 1::2] = 0
>>> matrix[1::2, ::2] = 0
>>> matrix
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 7],
       [2, 0, 4, 0, 7, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 7, 0, 9]])
```

You can also set every other value of `array` to zero then the constructed matrix will have zeros at desired locations:

```
>>> array[1::2]=0
>>> hankel(array[0:n], array[n:s])
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6],
       [0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 0],
       [2, 0, 4, 6, 0, 8],
       [0, 4, 6, 0, 8, 0]])
```

Comment: IIRC those special matrix functions while convenient are not exactly fast.

Comment: Yo Paul. If you continue to give me feedbaks about my answers I'l call you master! :) I think it shoud be fast but of course it depends on if the scipy.linalg.toeplitz was done by a trainee or not. Do you have some reference about the slowness of these functions?

Comment: See, for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/43735362/7207392 Glancing at the comments there it may be that scipy was patched and the functions are not slow anymore. One more remark: You can use `hankel` directly instead of flipping `toeplitz`

Comment: Even if you make copy in the end  `as_strided` is at least faster than my fancy indexing method.

Comment: Ok, I read through the entire comment thread and the special matrices were indeed patched (and PR accepted into scipy) by @Divakar himself. So you should be good performance wise. Can't +1 because already did.

Comment: @PaulPanzer No problem. Good to know that they improved the performance. And for readability of a scientific code, creating a matrix using the dedicated matrix name is even more important IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You can use advanced indexing into `array`. For efficiency, you can zero odd positions already in the template array.

```
np.where(np.arange(m+n)&1,0,array)[sum(np.ogrid[:n,:m])]
# array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
#        [0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6],
#        [2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0],
#        [0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8]])
```

or (faster)

```
template = np.where(np.arange(m+n)&1,0,array)
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(template,(n,m),2*template.strides)
```

This is a "compressed" view, if you need to modify the entries you must make a copy (it will still be faster).

Comment: @bousof `<strided_view>.copy()` will create a contiguously layed out version of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler way to create your table is:

1. Define a function:

   ```
    def tVal(r, c):
        sm = r + c
        return np.where(sm % 2 == 0, sm, 0)
   ```
2. Use it as an argument of *np.fromfunction*:

   ```
    arr = np.fromfunction(tVal, (n, m))
   ```

For your target shape (6 * 4) the result is:

```
array([[0., 0., 2., 0., 4., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 4., 0., 6.],
       [2., 0., 4., 0., 6., 0.],
       [0., 4., 0., 6., 0., 8.]])
```

Note than *tVal* is **not** actually called separately for each array
element.
It is instead called only **once**, with 2 **arrays** (*r* and *c*) shaped
as the target array, filled with respective arguments for each cell.
So this function operates on these arrays (not on single values for each
cell index).

This is why this function must contain *where*, not *if* for *r* and *c*
values for particular cell.

And a remark concerning variable names: *matrix* is a **class** in *Numpy*
(a subtype of *ndarray*), so it is a good practice **not** to use variables
with the same name. Use rather other name, as I did in my example.

Comment: This works for the case where the original array is generated as np.arange but this is not the real case, I only used that so that it was easy to tell what the final matrix should be. In general the values in the array vary widely. Can this be easily applied to that scenario?

Comment: You can use *fromfuncttion* as long as you are able to write
the funtion operating on 2 **arrays** filled with values (indices)
for each element. In more complex case you must iterate over
array elements. Read about *nditer*. It is an **iterator** operating
on *Numpy* arrays, but allows also access to indices of the current
element and *write* access to the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it directly at the numpy level:

```
matrix = np.arange(n * m).reshape(n,m)
matrix = matrix // m + matrix % m             # matrix // m is i and matrix % m is j
```

For `n, m = 4, 6` it gives as expected:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first example:

```
In [30]: arr=np.arange(24)                                                              
In [31]: [[arr[i+j] for i in range(6)] for j in range(4)]                               
Out[31]: 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

To take advantage of 'broadcasting':

```
In [32]: np.arange(4)[:,None]+np.arange(6)                                              
Out[32]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

The outer `i` loop is replaced by a (n,1) array; the inner `j` loop is replaced by the (m,) array; together the result is a (n,m) array.

Your more elaborate case:

```
In [35]: arr = np.arange(24) 
    ...: res = np.zeros((4,6),int) 
    ...: for i in range(4): 
    ...:     for j in range(6): 
    ...:         if (i+j)%2 ==0: 
    ...:             res[i,j] = arr[i+j] 
    ...:                                                                                
In [36]: res                                                                            
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6],
       [2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8]])
```

So this is the original, with just the even values set.

```
In [37]: Out[32]                                                                        
Out[37]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Find the odds:

```
In [38]: Out[32]%2                                                                      
Out[38]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Multiply:

```
In [39]: Out[32]*(Out[32]%2==0)                                                         
Out[39]: 
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6],
       [2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8]])
```

In general to make optimal use of `numpy`, I try to see overall patterns.  That's where small examples are especially valuable.